# How to do a silent install of MSYS on WIndows XP

Tags: installation, setup, installer, msys, silent-install

I have to install a set of development tools that includes MSYS 1.0.11 on a bunch of Windows XP boxes.

Every other tool is built with MSI or can simply be untarred or unzipped to the relevant install folders so they are all scripted. Eventually they'll all end up as part of a Microsoft System Centre Configuration manager package.

But... MSYS...

Are there any command line options for a silent install? I don't want to have to sit through the MSYS installer GUI on every PC.

Can't find anything on the MSYS homepage, http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS.

tl:dr - what's the command line for a slient install of MSYS 1.0.11?